# Possibility of writing dictionary items in columns

Tags: python

i have a dictionary in which keys are tuples and values are list like

```
{('c4:7d:4f:53:24:be', 'ac:81:12:62:91:df'): [5.998999999999998,0.0013169999,   
4.0000000000000972], ('a8:5b:4f:2e:fe:09', 'de:62:ef:4e:21:de'): [7.89899999,  
0.15647999999675390, 8.764380000972, 9.200000000]}
```

I want to write this dictionary to a csv file in the column format like:

```
('c4:7d:4f:53:24:be', 'ac:81:12:62:91:df')    ('a8:5b:4f:2e:fe:09', 'de:62:ef:4e:21:de')  
             5.998999999999998                      7.89899999  
             0.0013169999                           0.15647999999675390
             4.0000000000000972                     8.764380000972   
                                                    9.200000000
```

I know the same thing to write in row format using the code:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('dict.csv', 'wb'))
for key, value in mydict.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

How do i write the same thing in columns? Is it even possible? Thanks in advance
I referred python docs for csv here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. There is no information on column wise writing.

Comment: Just to clarify: keys are tuples and values are lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

mydict = {('c4:7d:4f:53:24:be', 'ac:81:12:62:91:df'):
          [5.998999999999998, 0.0013169999, 4.0000000000000972],
          ('a8:5b:4f:2e:fe:09', 'de:62:ef:4e:21:de'):
          [7.89899999, 0.15647999999675390, 8.764380000972, 9.200000000]}

with open('dict.csv', 'wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(mydict.keys())
    for row in zip(*mydict.values()):
        writer.writerow(list(row))
```

Output file dict.csv:

```
('c4:7d:4f:53:24:be', 'ac:81:12:62:91:df')  ('a8:5b:4f:2e:fe:09', 'de:62:ef:4e:21:de')
5.998999999999998   7.89899999
0.0013169999    0.1564799999967539
4.000000000000097   8.764380000972
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity...does this work even if there is only one key, i.e. only one column since the delimiter is "\t" in the program?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, it'll work fine with less than two columns. Regardless, you can change the delimiter to a comma. This will put them were necessary into the file because they'll be required in certain places due to the file format in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you can figure out the formatting:

```
>>> d.keys() #gives list of keys for first row
[('c4:7d:4f:53:24:be', 'ac:81:12:62:91:df'), ('a8:5b:4f:2e:fe:09', 'de:62:ef:4e:21:de')]
>>> for i in zip(*d.values()):  #gives rows with tuple structure for columns
        print i
(5.998999999999998, 7.89899999)
(0.0013169999, 0.1564799999967539)
(4.000000000000097, 8.764380000972)
```

For your code, do this:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('dict.csv', 'wb'))
writer.writerow(mydict.keys())  
for values in zip(*mydict.values()):
    writer.writerow(values)
```

The ()'s and such will not be added to the csv file.

Comment: how can i remove "(", ")" and "," symbols from output? I have like 25K entries in a single list. I cannot remove them manually. I want them in the format i specified because i need to plot these using excel or R-package

Comment: @Justin Carrey, see what I added above.