# In python2 how do I print a dictionary of lists to column format?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, multiple-columns

I currently have a dictionary of lists. I am trying to write them to an output in such a way that each dictionary key will be a column, and each corresponding list will fill that column, with each row for that column being a different element in the list. I feel like this should be a simple problem, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it correctly, because each approach I take yields the wrong output.

So I am trying to get something like this:

```
{'name1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'name2': [f, m, n], 'name3':     [a, c, e]}
```

to print out like so:

```
name1 <tab> name2 <tab> name3 <tab>...
a     <tab> f     <tab> a     <tab>...
b     <tab> m     <tab> c     <tab>...
c     <tab> n     <tab> e     <tab>...
```

Here is the code I've written that is definitely not doing it correctly... The first column always ends up with the most rows filled, followed by the second column, and so on:

```
outdict = {}
for name, mylist in newdict.iteritems():
   mylist = sorted(mylist)
   for x in range(0, len(mylist)):
      if x not in outdict:
         outdict[x] = []
      if x == 0:
         outdict[x].append(gene)
      else:
         outdict[x].append(mylist[x])

for a, b in outdict.iteritems():
   out = "\t".join(b)
   print out
```

Someone suggested that this question had been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734781/possibility-of-writing-dictionary-items-in-columns) but when I implemented the suggested code it still did not produce the correct output, and in fact it put the entire output in just two rows (the dictionary keys in one row and the dictionary values in a second row).

```
import csv
with open("test.tsv", "wb") as file:
   writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t')
   writer.writerow(newdict.keys())
   for row in zip(*newdict.values()):
      writer.writerow(list(row))
      writer.writerow("\n")
```

**FINAL UPDATE/SOLUTION:**
Just wanted to let everyone know that even though this question was incorrectly marked as duplicate with a user pointing me to code that did not solve the problem, I was ultimately able to solve the problem very easily using Pandas (as someone else suggested I look into). Here is the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd 
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k, v in newdict.iteritems()])) 
dataframe1.to_csv("testing.tsv", sep="\t")
```

This worked perfectly, and I also learned that I can export directly to Excel format using pandas too. I'm looking forward to getting more familiar with Pandas. Thanks!

Comment: If you really want to work with your data in something that works more like a table, consider restarting with an approach based on [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: Do the lists (dictionary values) always have the same number of items? ... Please add quotes to the items in the last two lists.

Comment: Hi @wwii. No, each list has a different number of elements.

Comment: Hi @TigerhawkT3 could you take a look at my attempt to implement the code you linked (now in the edited question)? The solution you linked to does not seem to work for me, and I'm not sure if I'm missing something or their solution just isn't the right one. Thanks!

Comment: Wanted to let everyone know that I could not get the code that @TigerhawkT3 linked when he marked my question as a duplicate to work, but I did manage to get this to work, so thanks very much to Sohier-Dane for suggesting Pandas!

    import pandas as pd
    dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k, v in newdict.iteritems()]))
    dataframe1.to_csv("testing.tsv", sep="\t")